# Social share module: confirmation page

Tags: webforms, nodes, media

I'm looking to add a the social share block only on the confirmation page. Right now it shows up everywhere. Is it possible to control where it goes?

Here's the path to a completed webform. 
node/1015/done?sid=1516

For Show block on specific pages I added 
node/*/done

Answer (score 0):

The node/*/done seems to be the fix. 
Just thought I'd pass it along.